# OpenCV Android Camera

Tags: android, opencv, communication

I'm working on a visible light communication project. I want to **recognize** a blinking light in *realtime* with android camera and **OpenCV** and every time that it flashes, a counter will increase by 1 (+1).

Is it worth trying with the **onCameraFrame** method or this is done via another method?

How can I get the value of light in a particular area of pixels?

Comment: OpenCV should be your option.

Comment: Of course i will use opencv but which method? OnCameraFrame method is correct to take value of specific area of pixels in realtime ?